# The number of context switches as reported by vmstat doesn't match up with the total of pidstat

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel

I am monitoring the number of context switches in a java application. `vmstat 1` gives cs per second globally. `pidstat -wt` also reports the cs per second for all the threads. This doesn't match up at all. The former is of the order of 40k whereas the latter is around 20-40 per second at max for a given process (much lower around 1 for most processes).

What is the reason for this mismatch? What is getting missed in the pidstat output?

Comment: Are you sure that `pidstat` does collect data for 1 second period of time? I don't think so, it just collects data at a particular instance and dumps on the screen whereas `vmstat` collects data for 1 second then shows the update.

Comment: **cswch/s** and **nvcswch/s** report the total number of voluntary and involuntary context switches per second, respectively.  The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pidstat) does not make it clear what period -w considers.